# Determine species of pear and harvest time for this location (Central Texas)

Tags: harvesting, variety-selection, pear

I'm finally getting into gardening and realize it takes a lot of invested time to learn even a fraction of what there is to know.  This pear tree below is the only one on my property, planted about 10 years ago.  Not sure if it's a Warren or Orient or other and appreciate help identifying.  From there I'd like help estimating the harvest date (Central Texas, and we've had a very wet spring and probably July also - and cooler than normal).  Can you identify the species and a resource then to figure harvest time?

Note, size is about 2/3 of a tennis ball right now

[image: Texas Hill Country Pear 1]
[image: Texas Hill Country Pear 2]
[image: Texas Hill Country Pear 3]